# How to recover a file which was overwritten using the "import" command?

Tags: files

I was working on a python script (a webscraper). I wanted to import the script into the python compiler (for no apparent reason). So, I unintentionally ran `import filename.py` in `bash` and now my file's gone now. Is there any way to recover it?

Answer (score 0):

Python's import command doesn't overwrite files. Exit Python using exit() and your file will be somewhere in the file system.

Comment: No joy! It's nowhere to be found.

Comment: btw, it's not Python's import command, but I'm talking about the bash command 'import.'

Comment: Not in a straightforward way.. Here is an article though that might help you. https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-restore-an-overwritten-file-on-linux

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is referring to this ImageMagick [import](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/import.php) command - which unfortunately takes an *output* file as its only argument

Comment: @Ryan and steeldriver Lesson learnt. I need to learn git. :-( Good thing the program had only a few LoC. I wrote it all back, Yay!